# Dynamically Update Key in Associative Array When Saving Settings

Tags: options, settings-api

I'm updating a WordPress plugin that I've built and realized that I've made a fairly large error in my original design. This is somewhat confusing, but I'll try to explain it as best I can.

On the admin page for my plugin, I currently have a "Number of Links" drop-down with options from 1 to 5. This controls the number of rows that show in a table below it. For every row in the table, the user must enter "Link Text" and, optionally, a "Link Image URL". For every link, a corresponding field shows up in a custom meta box on the Posts page. So for example, someone might enter a "Link Text" value of "Amazon", and in the meta box they will see an "Amazon URL" field where they can then supply a URL that will subsequently be shown for that post.

I've erroneously stored these links in the `wp_options` table as `book_review_link_text1`, `book_review_link_image1`, etc. Now I'm realizing that if someone were to swap the position of some of the links in the admin table (say they renamed "Amazon" to "Barnes & Noble" and "Barnes & Noble" to "Amazon"), the associated URLs that were saved in the meta box would now contain incorrect references. The Amazon anchor link would have a Barnes & Noble URL and vice versa.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to resolve this. Ideally, I'd like to get rid of the "Number of Links" drop-down and just have an "Add" button for adding new rows to the table, with the added abilities to delete an entire row or re-order them.

## Attempt 1

I figured that it would be best to store those rows as arrays in the database, something like `book_review_links[0][text]` and `book_review_links[0][image]`, with the `0` value coming from a hidden field in each table row. I threw this idea out after awhile because it was getting complicated to manage those IDs to ensure that they were unique when adding rows or re-ordering them.

## Attempt 2

So then I thought I could have the "Link Text" be the key and save them as `book_review_links['Amazon'][text]` and `book_review_links['Amazon'][image]` instead. The problem with that is that "Amazon" is a value that the user enters into the textbox, and so I don't know what that will be in advance in order to be able to assign it to the `name` attribute. Hence the initial reason for this post - is there a way to do that?

At this point, I've been staring at it for so long that I'm wondering if I'm over-thinking things and there's actually a much simpler solution that I'm not seeing. Does anyone out there see a better option?

Thx!

Comment: Move everything out of the wp_options table. Use post_meta or a custom table. A custom table would allow you to use an auto-increment ID as the 'key'. So it doesn't matter if they change the link text. Fields: id, post_id, text, image

Comment: Yes, that's sounding like the best option so far. I think I took the advice I seem to see everywhere about using existing WordPress tables too far and ended up backing myself into a corner. Oh well, learning experience for sure. Thx.